# openssl_csr_sign() is returning false when trying to sign with pre-generated CA and CA key

Tags: php, openssl, certificate

My project is to issue out certificates to users after they have entered the required information, the issue I run into is after I create the CSR (Certificate Signing Request) based on the info passed in, I try to sign it with CA and the CA key, but it fails and does not give an error.

I wanted to try and make sure that openssl_csr_sign method worked, so first I tried self signing the CSR and that worked, but that would satisfy the project requirement.

I also tried passing in the CA and the CA keys as strings (did not work), I tried sending them in with their path names (did not work), I found this information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.certparams.php)

I also removed the passphrase from the CA priv key just to make it as simple as possible

This is the php documentation for openssl_csr_sign [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-sign.php)

```
$dn = array(
    "countryName" => $_POST['country'],
    "stateOrProvinceName" => $_POST['state'],
    "localityName" => $_POST['loc'],
    "organizationName" => $_POST['orgName'],
    "organizationalUnitName" => $_POST['orgUnit'],
    "commonName" => $_POST['name'],
    "emailAddress" => $_POST['email']
);

// Generate a new private (and public) key pair
$privkey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));

// Generate a certificate signing request
$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey, array('digest_alg' => 'sha256'));

// Generate a certificate authority signed cert, valid for 365 days

$pathToPem = "./PulseSecureCA.crt"; # in my program, they are all absolute path names
$fileGetCert = file_get_contents('./PulseSecureCA.crt');

$fp = fopen($pathToPem, "r");
$CAAuth = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
echo "<br/>The Certificate Authority:<br/>".$CAAuth."<br/><br/>";

//$privkeytester = array(file_get_contents("./PulseSecureCA.key"),"abhi");

$pathToCAKey = "./PulseSecureCANoPass.key";
$fileGetKey = file_get_contents('./PulseSecureCANoPass.key');

$fp = fopen("./PulseSecureCANoPass.key", "r");
$CAAuthKey = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
echo "<br/>The Certificate Authority Key w/ no pass:<br/>".$CAAuthKey."<br/><br/>";
echo gettype($csr);

if (openssl_csr_sign($csr, $pathToPem, $CAAuthKey, 365, array('digest_alg'=>'sha256')) == FALSE)
    echo "breaking here<br/>";
else
    echo "signed Cert";
```

I expect the output to be signed Cert, but I am getting "breaking here" printed on the screen. I tried echo'ing everything to see what was majorly different but I am not sure what I need to do next to get it fixed. OPENSSL.cnf is active and in the right path, and when I run ehco php.info() it says openSSL is enabled. THERE IS NO ERROR PER SAY THAT IS PRINTED, I am completely lost

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code, you have not declared the location of the openssl.cnf file via the 'config' argument. Yes, you can let the application fall back to whatever default file it finds, but from what I've read, letting PHP/Apache fall back to the default openssl.cnf file can sometimes cause unexpected issues.

Please see the answer to this other question to see the minimum required sections in the cnf file: [Does OpenSSL really need a path to openssl.conf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570342/does-openssl-really-need-a-path-to-openssl-conf)

It's possible the issue is with some setting in your cnf file because I've compared your code to mine, for the same type of project, and it looks fine.